# Unable to serialize object into XML file

Tags: c#, xml, save

I'm trying to save a dictionary of Matrix into an Xml file.
My Matrix class attributes are :

```
public class Matrix 
{
    public int Lines { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    public double[,] Elements { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
 }
```

After many attempts, I wrote this :

```
string fileName = dlg.FileName;
Stream writer = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Create);

foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Matrix> matrice in CalMat.Calculatrice.listMatrix)
{
    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(matrice.GetType());
    x.Serialize(writer, matrice);
}

writer.Close();
```

If i run this code with one matrix, the file is created, but i only have this sentence written :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><KeyValuePairOfStringMatrix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" /><?xml version="1.0"?>
```

I think my code is missing something but I don't know what. A write method, I guess.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try using `System.Xml.XmlDictionary` and the related `XmlDictionaryReader` and Writer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BinaryFormatter this is the code:

```
[Serializable]  // mark with Serializable
public class Matrix
{
    public Matrix(string name, int lines, int columns)
    {
        Name = name;
        Lines = lines;
        Columns = columns;
        Elements = new double[Lines, Columns];
    }
    public int Lines { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    public double[,] Elements { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var path = @"D:\serialize.data"; // use the path that you want

    // this is an example collection
    var listMatrix = new Dictionary<string, Matrix>();
    listMatrix.Add("matrix_1", new Matrix("Matrix 1", 1, 2));
    listMatrix.Add("matrix_2", new Matrix("Matrix 2", 2, 2));

    // Serialization
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, listMatrix);
    stream.Close();

    // Deserialization
    stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    var result = (Dictionary<string, Matrix>)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Using XmlSerializer this is the code:

```
// I implement my custom KeyValuePair to serialize (because XmlSerializer can not serialize the .net KeyValuePair)
public struct CustomKeyValuePair<T1, T2>
{
    public CustomKeyValuePair(T1 key, T2 value): this()
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public T1 Key { get; set; }
    public T2 Value { get; set; }

    // here I specify how is the cast
    public static explicit operator CustomKeyValuePair<T1, T2>(KeyValuePair<T1, T2> keyValuePair)
    {
        return new CustomKeyValuePair<T1, T2>(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
}

// Matrix class used to Serialize with XmlSerailzer
public class Matrix
{
    public Matrix() { }  // need a default constructor
    public Matrix(string name, int lines, int columns)
    {
        Name = name;
        Lines = lines;
        Columns = columns;
        Elements = new double[Columns][];
        for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Length; i++)
        {
            Elements[i] = new double[Columns];
        }
    }
    public int Lines { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    public double[][] Elements { get; set; }  // I use double[][] because XmlSerialzer can not serialize a two-dimensional array (double[,])
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var path = @"D:\serialize.data"; // use the path that you want

    // this is an example collection
    var listMatrix = new Dictionary<string, Matrix>();
    listMatrix.Add("matrix_1", new Matrix("Matrix 1", 1, 2));
    listMatrix.Add("matrix_2", new Matrix("Matrix 2", 2, 2));

    // Serialization
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomKeyValuePair<string, Matrix>[]));
    var aux = listMatrix.Select(keyValuePair => (CustomKeyValuePair<string, Matrix>) keyValuePair).ToArray();
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, aux);  // I serialize an array to make easy the deserailizer
    stream.Close();

    // Deserialization
    stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    var result = (CustomKeyValuePair<string, Matrix>[])xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: I knew about the BinaryFormatter. I tried, and it works! =) Thank you for the help. But i am frustrated i could not make it work with the Xml.

Comment: @CAREAlexis if you want to use Xml you can't use the KeyValuePair from System.Collections.Generic. You need to create a custom KeyValuePair like the code that i proposed you

Comment: I tried that before working on the BinaryFormatter. I have an error, I can't cast the regular KeyValuePair into my own KeyValuePair. Do I need also to tell my dictionary to use my own keyValuePair?

Comment: @CAREAlexis of course you can't cast the .net KeyValuePair to your own KeyValuePair, you need to specify how is the cast. You can also say your dictionary to use your own KeyValuePair. I will post you all code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the default KeyValuePair is serializable,
try building your own KeyValuePair class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName="MyTypeName")]
public struct KeyValuePair<T1, T2>
{
  public T1 Key { get; set; }
  public T2 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do what you told, but I got an error. the program can't cast the default KeyValuePair<String,Matrix> (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<String,Matrix) into my own KeyValuePair<String,Matrix>
I don't know how to fix that :/